# Association for model - has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models - `Company`, `User` and `CompanyUser`. The associations are as follows.

Company.rb

```
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :users, :through => :company_users
```

User.rb

```
  has_many :company_users, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :company
```

CompanyUser.rb

```
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
```

For fetching current_user.company, what moddifications are to be made in the model association?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please write the output you get while using current_user.company on rails console?

Comment: you can not put your `FK` in user model so replace `belongs_to :company` with `hash_many :companies, :through => :company_users`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
has_many :companies, through: :company_users
```

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many
>   connection with another model. This association indicates that the
>   declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another
>   model by proceeding through a third model.

So if you are creating three models and making a `has_many :through` association I believe that `User will have many Companies` and `Company will have many Users`.

But if you need that the user belongs to only one `company` instead of creating the third model save the `company_id` in the `users` table itself.

**Update:**

Now as your scenario is `A company can have may users` and `User belongs to a single company`, you need two models: `User` and `Company`. Your `User` model should have an attribute `company_id` and then `company_id` should be saved in `users` table only. Then the associations as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Then you can do `current_user.company`

You can get more information on associations in the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)

Comment: The scenario is as follows.
A company can have may users. 
User belongs to a single company.
What would the model association for this if i want to fetch current_user.copmany ?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the associations you have taken,

user already have as association with the company through the Company User model, so user may have many companies according to your associations.

so,

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :company_users, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :companies, :through => :company_users

  end
```

`current_user.companies` will give you the companies.

But if you need only one company for a user then,

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :company
    end
```

take belongs_to company and save `company_id` in users table,

```
then you can call,

`current_user.company`
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic,
I think you may need to create a new variable session `current_company_user` which is object CompanyUser.
And then, to fetch company by :

```
current_company_user.company
```